# updating routes in navbar

Tags: navbar, observer-pattern, angular9

I'm writing a public web page at work, with angular 9, where the array of possible routes depends on the user's role.
I get the role from an HTTP request and the response updates an observable, that will be passed to a child component.

the problem is: the response is received but the template is not updated.

here it is components code:

```js
   

@Component({
  selector: 'navbar',
  template: `<nav-template [routesArray]="routesArrayObservable | async"></nav-template>`
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  private routesSubject: BehaviorSubject<AppRoute[]>;
  routesArrayObservable: Observable<AppRoute[]>;

  constructor(private accountService: AccountService) {
    this.routesSubject = new BehaviorSubject<AppRoute[]>(null);
    this.routesArrayObservable = this.routesSubject.asObservable();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.accountService.subscribableRole().subscribe((actualRole: string) => {
      this.routesSubject.next(ruoli[actualRole]);
    });
  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'nav-template',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
})
export class NavbarTemplate implements OnInit, OnChanges{
  @Input() routesArray: AppRoute[];
  user: Observable<User>;

  constructor(private accountService: AccountService){
    this.user = null;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.user = this.accountService.user;
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
    for (let propName in changes) {
      if (propName === 'routesArray'){
        this.routesArray = changes[propName].currentValue;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

and HTML template:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark"  *ngIf="user | async">
    <div class="navbar-nav" *ngIf="routesArray.length"> 
        <a *ngFor="let route of routesArray" class="nav-item nav-link" 
              routerLink="{{ route.routerLink }}">{{ route.name }}</a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-account">
        <nav-account></nav-account>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

resolved: the code in the subscribe() function wasn't in the NgZone.

I'm including another question with more data and explanation.

[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48670640/angular-5-cant-update-template-with-async-pipe)